# how to save current changes to a new branch later

Tags: git

If I am working in `FIX_XX_BUG` branch,

but I did some changes for a new feature,

but I don't want to commit these changes in the `FIX_XX_BUG` branch

and I'd rather commit them in a new branch for the new feature.(But the new branch I haven't create it)

How could I do ?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Answer (score 2):

A more detailed answer.

1. Save your changes in a stash, here's the docs http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing
2. Complete works on the current branch
3. Switch to a new branch at a desired branchpoint
4. Apply your stash. You may get some conflicts at this point, you have to resolve it.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you don't want to deal with stash management, is to create a branch right where you are (supposing you didn't add anything yet to the index):

```
git checkout -b aNewBranch
git add -p
git commit -m "new feature"

git checkout FIX_XX_BUG
```

The private files won't be affected by those branches, ad `add -p` helps you add only what you need.

The last checkout will restore your index *without* the new features modifications (which remains committed in the new branch).

The idea will be *later* to *rebase* your feature-branch on top of any branch you need to re-apply your new feature commits.
So it doesn't matter that it is branches from your bug-fixing branch: you will relocate it where it does make sense.
For instance, on top of `master`:

```
 git checkout newFeatureBranch
 git rebase master
```

Comment: The method can actually be useful if you don't mind to branch your feature-branches from bug-branches

Comment: @user3159253 it doesn't matter: you will rebase that branch anyway